# How can I approximate the logarithm of the sum?

Tags: logarithms

Consider $\alpha = \log a$ and $\beta = \log b$, $b>a$. Are there formulas for approximating $\gamma = \log (a+b)$? What about $\theta = \log (a-b)$?

If it makes it easier, assume that $|\alpha| \gg 300$ so the obvious solution $\gamma = \log (10^\alpha + 10^\beta)$ is infeasible using standard double-precision floating point arithmetic (you can't easily store $a$ and $b$ in memory to begin with!).

Answer (score 2):

you can try this here
$\gamma=\log\left[a\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)\right]$=
$\log(a)+\log\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)$

Comment: which, if $\beta$ is much larger than $\alpha$, then $\log(1 + \frac{b}{a})$ is approximately $\log(\frac{b}{a}) = \log(b) - log(a)$ and the entire thing degrades to approximately $log(b)$.

Comment: Since $b>a$, a better approximation would be $\log b+\log(1+a/b)\approx\log b+(a/b)=\beta+\exp(\alpha-\beta)$.

Comment: @Rahul Wait, is $\log(1+\frac ab) \simeq \frac a b$?! That sounds... very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Working in [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838311/909869) I found that for positive $x,y$ you could approximate:
$$\ln(x+y)\approx \begin{cases} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}\ln(x)-y^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}\ln(y)}{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-y^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}}, \quad x\neq y\\ \ln(x)+\ln(2),\quad x=y \end{cases}$$

which is based in this other approximation:
$$\ln(1+e^x) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{x}{1-e^{-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}},\quad x\neq 0\\ \ln(2),\quad x=0\end{cases}$$

For the last one the [maximum error is below](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max+%7Cln%281%2Be%5Ex%29-+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29%7C) $0.0092$, and the [plot is quite close](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%281%2Be%5Ex%29%2C+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29):

[image: comparison of the plots]

Comment: What do you mean quite close, it's almost exact! +1

Comment: quite and almost are words that sometimes let you in trouble in this site lol. If $x+y\to 0$ you could have issues since $\ln(x)$ "explodes" to negative infinite faster: plot the relation for $x$ with $y=1$ and you will see it... for very small $x$ the logarithm is better approximated by $\ln(x)\approx \frac{1-x^{-x}}{x}$